# Sound output in speakers even with bluetooth headset connected

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headset, speaker

I use a bluetooth headset (Motorola S305) with my Nexus 4 (Stock 4.4.2) but when my phone rings or I receive a notification the sound comes in both, speakers and headset, I want to set everything to the headset, is that possible?